# Simple piece wise smooth curve example in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I have studied that a simple piece wise smooth curve is called as contour in complex analysis. Could anybody explain me simple piece wise smooth curve definition with example in Complex analysis? More specifically I need an example of such curve with justification.

**My understanding**: In real, a well known example of the modulus function $|x|$ can be considered as piece wise smooth function. Function $|x|$ is continuous and its derivative exist everywhere except at zero. So two differentiable piece of the function $|x|$ are $-x$ for $x<0$ and $x$ for $x\geq 0$.

Thanking you

Comment: It's exactly the same thing: you identify $\Bbb C=\Bbb R^2$ in the canonical way and call "piece-wise smooth curve" a piece-wise smooth curve $[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ (or your favourite interval as domain).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks for the reply. Can I take function $f(t) = t+it$ when $t<0$ and $f(t) = t+it$ when $t \geq 0 $ as an example?

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same thing: you identify $\Bbb C=\Bbb R^2$ in the canonical way $z=x+iy$ and then you call "piece-wise smooth curve" a piecewise smooth curve $[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ - or with your favourite interval as a domain.

Typical instances of simple, closed and piecewise smooth curves on the complex plane are rectangular paths with sides parallel to real and imaginary axis, such as $$r_{\xi,\zeta}(t)=\begin{cases}\xi+t\Re(\zeta-\xi)&\text{if }0\le t<1\\ \Re \zeta+i\Im\xi+i(t-1)\Im(\zeta-\xi)&\text{if }1\le t<2\\ \zeta+(t-2)\Re(\xi-\zeta)&\text{if }2\le t<3\\ \Re \xi+i\Im\zeta+i(t-3)\Im(\xi-\zeta)&\text{if }3\le t\le4\end{cases}$$ This parametrizes the boundary of one with $\xi$ and $\zeta$ as opposite vertices, with $\xi$ being the base point. It's counteclockwise if $\Re(\zeta-\xi)\Im(\zeta-\xi)>0$ and clockwise when $\Re(\zeta-\xi)\Im(\zeta-\xi)<0$.